# DevOps (yml) build and deploy of ASPNET (4.8) misses the correct structure

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, yaml, azure-web-app-service

My YML-pipeline does not work correctly.
This is the resulting set of files deployedto my app service (files have been omitted to keep list short),

```
Directory of C:\home\site\wwwroot\a

06/14/2023  12:52 PM           103,424 Antlr3.Runtime.dll
06/14/2023  12:52 PM           435,712 Antlr3.Runtime.pdb
.
.
06/14/2023  12:55 PM    <DIR>          _PublishedWebsites
```

it is clear that I archive wrong level of files and I probably also get the parms of  **msbuildArgs:** wrong. Using a publishing profile from within VS2022, file structure are correct and the app is working as expected:

```
 Directory of D:\home\site\wwwroot

06/14/2023  08:24 AM    <DIR>          .
06/14/2023  08:24 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/14/2023  08:24 AM    <DIR>          Areas
06/14/2023  08:24 AM    <DIR>          bin
06/14/2023  08:24 AM    <DIR>          Content
05/31/2023  01:45 PM            32,038 favicon.ico
06/14/2023  08:14 AM               102 Global.asax
06/14/2023  07:24 AM             3,269 hostingstart.html
06/14/2023  08:24 AM    <DIR>          Scripts
06/14/2023  08:24 AM    <DIR>          Views
06/14/2023  09:28 AM             4,379 Web.config
```

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this with VSBuild@1 and AzureWebApp@1 in conjunction.

My pipeline looks like

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '${{parameters.solution}}'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:OutputPath="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'


- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs: 
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

- script: dir D:\a\1 /s
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish build artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  displayName: 'My-API Backend Service'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{parameters.azureSubscription}}'
    appType: 'webAppWindows'
    appName: '${{parameters.appServiceName}}'`
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

I find a lot of older threads on this but often with invalid parms, so I have tried to keep the yml as simple as possble, but apparently too simple.

How should yml look?

Thanks

**UPDATE #1**
I cheated by creating a defaulu ASPNET classic pipeline which worked as a charm and exported the yaml. Then I updated the tasks:

- VSBUild@1
- ArchieveFile@2

with

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: Build solution ${{parameters.solution}}
  inputs:
    solution: ${{parameters.solution}}
    msbuildArgs: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish **/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem** **/p:publishUrl="$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\\"**
    platform: $(BuildPlatform)
    configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs: 
    rootFolderOrFile: **$(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent**
    includeRootFolder: false
```

publishURL was new new to me and together with 'FileSystem' as 'webPublishMethod' fixed the problem.

Comment: All you need to do is change the YAML to publish the appropriate subdirectory. I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: I'm just confused with the purpose of "/p:WebPublishMethod=Package" which create a folder "D:\a\1\a\_PublishedWebsites\faelles_Package" with

06/14/2023  01:28 PM             4,002 faelles.deploy-readme.txt
06/14/2023  01:28 PM            14,447 faelles.deploy.cmd
06/14/2023  01:28 PM               162 faelles.SetParameters.xml
06/14/2023  01:27 PM               428 faelles.SourceManifest.xml
06/14/2023  01:28 PM        12,567,800 faelles.zip

I haven't a seen any documentation, that this specific folder should be published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Instead of using VSBuild use Dotnetcore build tasks and then Publish the Artifact and deploy your asp.net core app from the published zip artifact in your yaml pipeline. I tried deploying Asp.Net app with Yaml pipeline in Azure DevOps and it was successful, Refer below:-*

**My YAML pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '6.x'

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  inputs:
    version: 6.x
    performMultiLevelLookup: true
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)' # Update this to match your need


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

# this code takes all the files in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and uploads them as an artifact of your build.
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'subscription'
    appType: 'webApp'
    appName: 'siliconwebap'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**My Published Artifact:-**

[image]

[image]